# Application freezes every time I check for FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog

Tags: android, facebook

Everytime I run:

```
if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(), 
    FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)
```

the application freezes. My emulator does not have the facebook app installed.

On my android device(HTC one m7), having facebook app installed everything(open graph story posting, login/logout) works fine.

Sadly I cannot delete facebook entirely on my device (preinstalled) to check if I get the same freeze not having fb app installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A facebook SDK update helped somehow.